# Only enable ServiceAccounts for some pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I use the Kubernetes ServiceAccount plugin to automatically inject a ca.crt and token in to my pods. This is useful for applications such as kube2sky which need to access the API Server.

However, I run many hundreds of other pods that don't need this token. Is there a way to stop the ServiceAccount plugin from injecting the default-token in to these pods (or, even better, have it off by default and turn it on explicitly for a pod)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Kubernetes 1.6+ you can now disable automounting API credentials for a particular pod as stated in the [Kubernetes Service Accounts documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now there isn't a way to enable a service account for some pods but not others, although you can use ABAC to for some service accounts to restrict access to the apiserver.

This issue is being discussed in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16779 and I'd encourage you to add your use can to that issue and see when it will be implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is it feasible then to disable the ServiceAccount plugin and manage them myself for the few pods that actually need them?

Comment: Yes. You can create a secret that contains a valid client credential (bearer token or http basic auth password) that is valid for your cluster. You would then add this secret to any pod which needs api access and all other pods won't have credentials. If you want the default "InClusterConfig" to work out of the box (assuming you are using the Go k8s client libraries) then you should mount the secret into the location where the service account credentials are mounted. If you are not relying on that specific location for the credentials then mounting them anywhere in the pod will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!